# how to mock this.$refs.form.resetValidation()?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

component1.vue

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <v-form
        ref="form">
            <v-text-field
                v-model="name"
                :counter="10"
                :rules="nameRules"
                label="Name"
                required
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      name: 'Test',
      nameRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Name is required',
        v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
      ]
    }),

    mounted() {
        this.$refs.form.resetValidation();
    }
  }
</script>
```

test.spec.js

```
import { shallowMount, mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from "vuex"
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import component1 from '@/components/component1.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(Vuetify)
const vuetify = new Vuetify()

test('test1', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(component1, {
        localVue,
        vuetify
    })
    expect(3).toBe(3);
})
```

Error - TypeError: this.$refs.form.resetValidation is not a function

If i were to use mount instead of shallowMount, the test will pass. But I would want to know how to mock $ref.form.resetValidation.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a manual stub to the replace the one that would otherwise get used for the v-form:

```
test('test1', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(component1, {
    localVue,
    stubs: {
      VForm: {
        render: () => {},
        methods: {
          resetValidation: () => ()
        }
      }
   }
})
....
```

})